# Distribution of the maximum of a large number of normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_i\sim \text{iid}\, \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. I am interested in the random variable $Y=\max_i{X_i}$ when $n$ is large. From [Extreme value theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory) it seems that $Y$ would follow a Gumbel distribution but I would like to know the parameters of this distribution as a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Also, would the result holds if $\mu$ and $\sigma$ differ across $i$ or if the $X_i$ are not independent?

Comment: Recall that the standard normal CDF $\Phi$ is such that $$1-\Phi(y)\sim\frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ when $y\to\infty$ and that, for every $y$ $$P(Y_n\leqslant\mu+y\sigma)=\Phi(y)^n$$ hence, if $(y_n)$ is chosen such that $$n\frac{e^{-y_n^2/2}}{y_n\sqrt{2\pi}}=t$$ for some given $t$, then $$P(Y_n\leqslant\mu+y_n\sigma)\to e^{-t}$$ Solving this for $y_n$ yields $$y_n=\sqrt{2\ln n}-\frac{\ln\ln n+2\ln t+\ln(4\pi)}{2\sqrt{2\ln n}}$$ Equivalently, defining
$$Z_n=\sqrt{2\ln n}\frac{Y_n-\mu}\sigma-2\ln n+\frac12\ln\ln n+\frac12\ln(4\pi)$$
yields the (well known) convergence ...

Comment: ... in distribution $$Z_n\to Z$$ where, for every real $z$, $$P(Z\leqslant z)=\exp(-e^{-z})$$

Comment: Thanks @Did that's useful. So I guess $$\text{Var}(Z_n)=\frac{2\ln n}{\sigma^2}\text{Var}(Y_n)$$ and since $\text{Var}(Z_n)=\pi^2/6$ we can get the variance of $Y_n$ this way? By the way, if you want to post your note as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: You mean, Var$(Z)=\pi^2/6$, not Var$(Z_n)=\pi^2/6$?

Comment: Yes. So for $n$ large enough we would find $$ \text{Var}(Y_n)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2\ln n}$$

Comment: Not equal, at most an equivalent (even for large values of $n$).

Comment: @Did can you elaborate more on moving from the $\text{Var}(Z_n)$ to  $\text{Var}(Y_n)$ , like a completer proof for a beginner like me :)

Comment: This post on the stats site is relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/105745/119261. Also see the linked threads.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take a look at the [Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem)

Comment: Yes, I know this result. My question is what are the $a_n$ and $b_n$. For instance, I would like to know the variance of the distribution $Y$.